# How to make the footer to be full width?

Tags: html, css

How to make full width footer with `<footer>` tag. 
I'm **not able to use div** with id and make it looks like footer (which is pretty simple).

```css
body{
    background: #333333;
}
footer{
    float:left;
    background: lime;
    padding:15px 0;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<footer></footer>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g4b3oakd/

**When i use code like this it's not in full width of page.** 
Is possible to do something like this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: Thank you, next time I do it this way.

Comment: Why are you not able to use a `div`?

Comment: @Tim It's project restriction.

Comment: Try using min-width:100% instead of width:100%

Comment: He gave the snippet, he gave the minimal example, his question is clear, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `margin: 0;` like this: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/g4b3oakd/1/

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    background: #333333;
}
footer{
    float:left;
    background: lime;
    padding:15px 0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Additionally, I would advise to include something like [Normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to quickly get rid of all browser inconsistencies.

Comment: Yes, that's work, but it's possible to use margin attribute somewhere else? Not in body?

Comment: @Nefritox I don't think I understand. The body has a margin of i think 8px by default, so by changing it to 0 you are now able to goo 100% width to cover the whole screen, so as I understand your question now, I would say no there is not.

Comment: @Adam Buchanan Smith, thank you for answer